# Get text inside an HTML element, store it in a variable and add class to all the other matches in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to achieve this:

I have this code:

```
<h1>Search results for "<span>photoshop</span>"</h1>
```

And, I have another code like this in the same page:

```
<p>Photoshop is the best photo editor in the world</p>
```

With jQuery or pure JavaScript, I want to get the word within the span which changes dynamically, store it in a variable, and wrap every other 'photoshop' word in the document with a 'highlighted' class. How can I do this?

Comment: _"WIth jQUery or pure javascript"_ => so why the php-tag?

Comment: are you able to give span an id? e.g. make it `<h1>Search results for "<span id='mySpan'>photoshop</span>"</h1>` ?

Comment: @asifrc, yes I can give it an id.

Comment: Barbara's answer should work fine for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression and jQuery's html() function to find and replace all occurances of a word with that word wrapped in a span.

```
<h1>Search results for "<span id="search">Photoshop</span>"</h1>

var theWord = $('#search').text(),
    patt=new RegExp('\\b(' + theWord + ')\\b', 'gi');

$('body').html($('body').html().replace(patt,'<span class="highlight">$1</span>'));
```

(use 'gi', if you want it to be global and case insensitive)

http://jsfiddle.net/EBWQX/2/

and if you can't give the span an id, maybe selecting $('h1 span') would be specific enough (depending on your code)

Comment: I don't have a clue why, but it's making my site to not work. I put it right before closing the body tag, but it keeps loading forever.

Comment: I changed BODY to the div I was targeting, and now it's working perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Did you wrap the javascript in $( document ).ready()?  Btw, targetting a div is much better than doing the whole document.

Comment: If I enter a `table` into `#search` span it's broke all table tags.

Comment: Are you saying you're no longer searching for text, but now you're searching for a table tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [jQuery Highlight Plugin](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html).

Example [there](http://jsfiddle.net/EBWQX/3/):

HTML:

```
<input onkeyup="setNewSearch(this);" />  
<h1>Search results for "<span id="search"></span>"</h1>  
<!-- text -->
```

Javascript:

```
function setNewSearch(input){
    var value = $(input).val();
    $("#search").html(value);
    $("body").unhighlight();
    $("body").highlight(value);
}
```

Comment: This is a better option.  It handles ignoring the html tags, etc.